# Modifying existing XLSX with Macros/Graphs with Node

Tags: node.js, xlsx

So I am trying to insert a couple rows into an excel document that has graphs and macros.

However, it seems like xlsx and node-excel parses out the excel before writing so all of the information regarding styling, graphs, and macros get lost.

Does anyone know if its possible to accomplish this with node.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sundagy/slim-xlsx

This libary can insert & edit rows with preserving styles, maby it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

[xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate) tries to keep existing workbook features and styles intact. I tested it with chart objects within the Excel file and they survived.

```
const XlsxPopulate = require("xlsx-populate");

async function test1() {
   const wb = await XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync("c:/temp/test.xlsx");
   const sheet = wb.sheet(0);
   sheet.cell("A1").value("Hello!");
   await wb.toFileAsync("c:/temp/testOut.xlsx");
}

test1();
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking into consideration how you need to interface with the xlsx files, it would be a good idea to structure your project-feature accordingly; here is an NPM module that interfaces very well with xslx documents:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

-and here is the Github repo, with 56 contributors at this time of writing:
https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs